# Why does multiprocessing.Queue stuck when parent process of fork() puts to the queue before fork?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fork

I recently write this program:

```py
import os, time
from multiprocessing import Queue

q = Queue(1000)

q.put(1)     # Line 6

result = os.fork()
if result == 0:
    while True:
        q.put(2)
        time.sleep(1)
elif result > 0:
    while True:
        print(q.get())
else:
    raise Exception('Fork failed: %d' % result)
```

The program uses `os.fork()` to create a child process. The child process constantly sends `2` to the queue, and the parent process constantly reads from the queue.

I am expecting to see "1 2 2 2 2 2 ..." as the output (here I am collapsing the lines for concision), but actually I only see "1" and the program stucks. Is it a deadlock? Did I do something wrong, or is it a bug of Python's `multiprocess.Queue`?

If I remove line 6, the output is "2 2 2 ...", which is expected.

Note: I see some related questions on stackoverflow mention calling `Queue.join_thread()` before exit. However, my program doesn't have this problem because none of the processes exit.

If it is relevant, I am on Linux with Python 3.11.2 . I also tried Python 3.9.18 .

Comment: Update Python 3.11.7

Comment: @toyota Supra Updating to Python 3.11.7 does not help. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Python 3.12 and Python 3.13 (rc), and I receive a warning when running my program, which solves the mystery:

```
a.py:10: DeprecationWarning: This process (pid=1234) is multi-threaded, use of fork() may lead to deadlocks in the child.
  result = os.fork()
```

So it appears that putting to the `Queue` creates a new thread, and then calling `os.fork()` causes deadlock.

Comment: The Python 3.13.7 final will be released October 10, 2024